# Cannot rm -rf directories copied via COPY --chown user:group in the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I cannot understand why I am not able to remove directories copied with `COPY --chown user:group` as the `user` inside my container.

File tree:

```
.
├── Dockerfile.copy
├── Dockerfile.run
└── build
    └── file.txt
```

*Dockerfile.copy*

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN addgroup -g 98765 -S mygroup && adduser -S -u 56789 -G mygroup -D myuser
COPY --chown=myuser:mygroup build /opt/app/build
USER myuser:mygroup
```

in the CLI:

```
$ docker build --file=Dockerfile.copy --tag=copy:latest --progress="plain" .
> ... building

$ docker run copy:latest whoami
> myuser

$ docker run copy:latest ls -altrh
> total 12K
> drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jan 13 09:25 ..
> drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser   mygroup     4.0K Jan 13 09:26 build
> drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jan 13 09:26 .

$ docker run copy:latest rm -rf build
> rm: can't remove 'build': Permission denied
```

Error received when running `rm -rf build` is:

> rm: can't remove 'build': Permission denied

Whereas in the other image, when I use `RUN chown`, I am able to remove the directory without errors.

*Dockerfile.run*

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN addgroup -g 98765 -S mygroup && adduser -S -u 56789 -G mygroup -D myuser
COPY build /opt/app/build
RUN chown -R myuser:mygroup /opt/app
USER myuser:mygroup
```

then in CLI:

```
$ docker build --file=Dockerfile.run --tag=run:latest --progress="plain" .
> ... building
$ docker run run:latest rm -rf build
> (nothing, no errors)
```

My docker version:

```
$ docker --version
> Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f
```

Why is that, what am I missing and don't understand about the `COPY --chown user:group`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first Dockerfile, `myuser` owns `/opt/app/build`.

In your second Dockerfile, `myuser` owns `/opt/app`.

To be able to remove the directory, you need access to modify `/opt/app`.